# Plotting an expression involving the inverse error function

Tags: plotting, special-functions

I solved some equation in Mathematica and I obtained something like
$$y(t)=\exp \left\lbrace \left[ \text{erf}^{-1} (\text{i}t) \right]^2\right\rbrace, (1)$$
where $\text{i}$ is imaginary unit and $\text{erf}^{-1}(x)$ is the **inverse error function** (it is not equal to $\frac{1}{\text{erf}(x)}$ !!), which is defined for $x \in [-1,1]$. The problem is that the $t$ is real and the function has to be also real, but I can't plot this function since $\text{erf}^{-1}$ accepts only real arguments in Mathematica. Is there any way how to plot the solution or convert it to some other expression, which can be plotted? I tried to use some approximations of inverse error functions, such as
$$ \text{erf}^{-1}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{N} \frac{c_k}{2k+1}\left(\frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}x\right)^{2k+1}, (2)$$
to finite $N$ (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Inverse_functions))
which holds if $x \in [-1,1]$ and then I just simply put $t \rightarrow \text{i}t$ in approximated version of (1) and obtained only real part (imaginary part was zero), but I'm not sure wheather it is correct.

Comment: Can you show the Mathematica code? Because when I typed `y = Exp[(Erf[I t]^(-1))^2]; Plot[y, {t, -1, 1}]` I get this ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1u1zv.png)

Comment: The $\text{erf}^{-1}(x)$ is not $\frac{1}{\text{erf}(x)}$, but an inverse function of $\text{erf}(x)$, as explained above. The $\text{erf}^{-1}(x)$ function is represented in Mathematica as `InverseErf[x]`. The code I use is `Plot[{Re[Exp[InverseErf[I x]]^2], Im[Exp[InverseErf[I x]]^2]}, {x, -1,
   1}]`

Comment: From help for InverserErf it says `Explicit numerical values are given only for real values of s between -1 and +1.` But you have complex arguments.

Comment: On http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/InverseErf/04/01/ you can read that `InverseErf` is a function $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. I'm asking how to modify the expression $\text{erf}^{-1}(\text{i}t)$ so it can be plotted.

Comment: It looks like Matlab might be able to do [complex inverse error function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/erfinv.html) calculations, see "To compute the inverse error function for complex numbers, first convert them to...". A Mathematica fix would be best, obviously, but I'm not sure how to do that. You can always check the quality of your series approximation $\text{Erf}^{-1}(iz)$ by feeding the result to `Erf` and see how close the result is to $iz$. Have you tried that, to see if your approximation is any good?

Comment: Hmm, so it looks like the main inverse branch of $\text{Erf}(iz)$ lies along the imaginary axis, so it shouldn't be too hard to estimate the inverse function. I'll post an answer in a while if I find anything remotely useful.

Comment: Okay, so it looks like $\text{Erf}^{-1}(iz)=i\text{Erfi}^{-1}(z)$, and $\text{Erfi}$ is purely real-valued, so it suffices to use `I InverseFunction[Erfi]`. Does that help? You then get $y(t)=\exp(-\text{Erfi}^{-1}(t)^2)$, which is purely real-valued.

Comment: @Nasser: The reason that `InverseErf` only gives explicit numerical values for real values of s between -1 and +1 is because of the complicated branch structure of the inverse error function. However, for purely imaginary argument, an inverse branch lies along the imaginary axis, and the problem is well-defined (see graphic at the bottom of my answer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately *Mathematica* seems to be a bit silly here, but a little math can give a workaround. In particular, we have
$$\text{Erf}^{-1}(iz)=i\text{Erfi}^{-1}(z)$$
which means 
$$y(t)=\exp\left(-\text{Erfi}^{-1}(t)^2\right)$$
and $\text{Erfi}$ is purely real-valued for real $t$.

Because of this, if you are simply interested in plotting $y(t)$, then one way to do it is to avoid the inverse-map altogether, forward-map the $x$-axis, and then take that into account when constructing the plot:

```
ListLinePlot[Table[{Erfi[t], Exp[-t^2]}, {t, -2, 2, 0.1}], 
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]

From this same approach, you can also define an interpolating function based on the above datapoints using the function `Interpolation`, and get reasonably accurate estimates of $y(t)$ at arbitrary $t$. The advantage of this approach is it avoid the use of complicated series approximations, and is still very accurate.

*Additional unrelated fun stuff*: the $\text{Erf}$ function maps purely imaginary values to purely imaginary values in a 1-to-1 manner, so it makes sense that $\text{Erf}^{-1}(iz)=if(z)$ for some real-valued function $f$. A visual proof of this fact can be obtained by plotting the sign of the imaginary component of $\text{Erf}(z)$ times a function which has peaks when the phase of $\text{Erf}(z)$ is $\pm\pi/2$:

```
hue = Compile[{{z, _Complex}}, {(1.0 Arg[-z] + π)/(2 π), 
    Exp[1 - Max[Abs[z], 1]], Min[Abs[z], 1]}, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
CCompile\[DoubleStruckCapitalC][expr_] := 
  Compile[{{z, _Complex}}, Evaluate[expr], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
dat = CCompile\[DoubleStruckCapitalC][Erf[z]][
   Outer[Complex, Range[-5, 5, 0.015], Range[-5, 5, 0.015]]];
f[c_] := Sign[Im[c]]/(
  Abs[Arg[c] - π/2] Abs[π/2 + Arg[c]] + 0.1);
Image[hue[Map[f, dat, {2}]\[Transpose]/7], ColorSpace -> Hue]
```

[image]

The principal branch of the inverse function is the vertical line (which is what we want), and the other lobes are other branches of $\text{Erf}^{-1}$.

Comment: This looks amazing, thank you for help. I found out the problem in Maple, but this is better since everything is in one MAthematica notebook. I also found out that is it okay to put z -> iz in the series above (2) and it fits with result obtained from Maple.

Comment: Any reason why you didn't do `ParametricPlot[{Erfi[t], Exp[-t^2]}, {t, -2, 2}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]`?

Comment: Oh~~That's a really smart way of plotting  complex Inverse function @J. M.